# Sort results by column name while seeing structure of a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

While seeing the structure of a table in **Sql Server 2008** using the `alt+F1` command, in the results window the order of columns in same as that at the time of creation of the table. Cant we change to order the results alphabetically?

Comment: No. You would need to drop the table and recreate it with an alphabetized column order to do that. I wouldn't recommend that as it will destroy the statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [Information Schema Views (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)

You might also want to have a look at this helpfull article

[SQL Server Troubleshooting Tips and Tricks](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/SQL_Server_Troubleshooting_Tips_and_Tricks)